# Create standard dsl and receive parameters with groovy

Tags: jenkins, grails, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-groovy

I have a problem, how can I create a dsl base script which receives parameters and thus have a dsl script base for the creation and configuration of job in jenkins using groovy ?. My idea is to have a base script for the creation of jobs and only change details, such as the name.
Thank you

Comment: What DSL are you talking about? [Job DSL](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl), [Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/)?

Comment: I'm talking about Job DSL.

Answer (score 1):

There are some example well hidden in the Job DSL documentation:

- https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands#dsl-factory
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Real-World-Examples#import-other-files-ie-with-class-definitions-into-your-script